# How can I change the background color of elements when they're clicked?

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of div elements in a ReactJS projects. I want to just get an indication when someone clicks change the background color.

the following is the basic code.

```
function changetoselected(event){
    // now change backgroundColor of
    // event.currentTarget to white
}

<div>
bigarrayofsize100plus.map((item,index) =>{
    return(
         <div 
            className="p-2" 
            onClick={(e) => changetoselected(e)} 
            style={{backgroundColor:"green"}}
         >
            .....
         </div>
    )
}
</div>
```

I dont want to store in the state all the elemets uncessarily. I dont have to trace clicked items here.

If once clicks i want to just change color. How can i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the style property to set a backgroundColor like this.

```js
function changetoSelected(event){
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'
}
```

You can also use [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) in React like this

For a **Function Component** do this
`

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const divEl = useRef(null);

  const changeToSelected = () => {
    divEl.current.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  };

  return (
      <div ref={divEl} onClick={changeToSelected}>
        ...
      </div>
  );
}
```

For a **Class Component** do this

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.divElement = React.createRef();
  }
  
  changetoselected = () => {
    this.divElement.current.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.divElement} onClick={this.changetoselected}>
        ...
      </div>;
  }
}
```

After all, working with pure dom (by ref or event) may not be what you are searching for, you can consider using react state and apply className or style to your dom elements

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState('green');

  return (
      <div 
        onClick={() => setBackgroundColor('white')} 
        style={{ backgroundColor }}
      >
        ...
      </div>
  );
}
```

**EDIT**

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const divEl = useRef(null);

  const changeToSelected = () => {
    divEl.current.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  };

  return (
      <div>
         {bigarrayofsize100plus.map((item,index) =>
           <ChildComp
             key={index}
             item={item}
           >
              .....
           </div>
          )}
      </div>
  );
}
```

```js
function ChildComp({ item }) {
  const divEl = useRef(null);

  const changeToSelected = () => {
    divEl.current.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  };

  return (
      <div
        ref={divEl}
        onClick={changeToSelected}
        className="p-2" 
        style={{backgroundColor:"green"}}
      >
        // do stuff with item heere
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: the last solution will change all the elements. with `style={{ backgroundColor }}`

I just edited the question. can you check

Comment: the first and second solutions with a little tweaking should still work for you. You just need to wrap what you're maping through in its own component

Comment: `event.target.style.backgroundColor` this worked for me

Comment: curious how `const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState('green');` this will work in this scenario

Comment: but it will change all the divs colors

Comment: No, it won't if you move it into the child component.